'Invoke Method' activity is missing in UIPath
I am not able to find 'Invoke Method' in my Activities panel. I have not filtered the activities. I am using UiPath.System.Actvities package version 24.11.0-preview. I tried to rollback up to 24.3.1 but that didn't help either. Any help?

It is system problem from UiPath.

We will resurface it in the next version, our bad (it had a broken view in cross-platform projects, so it was only meant to be hidden in those ones, not windows ones as well).

https://forum.uipath.com/t/unable-to-locate-invoke-method-
activity/766411/3

Was renamed to Invoke Com Method.

I doubt that. Isn't 'Invoke Com' activity used to invoke methods of COM objects? Prog ID is one of the required parameter of this. The invoke method on the other hand is supposed to invoke methods from .NET objects created within UIPath workflow
